# Swashbuckle not displaying methods that have a collection as a paramater

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a Web API (WebApi 2). I am trying to use Swashbuckle for documentation. I have a GET method that takes a List as a paramater. The method works but does not show up in the Swashbuckle documentation.

```
[RoutePrefix("myroute")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{foo}/{bar}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri]List<string> foo, string bar)
    {            
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

How do I get a List or array to work with Swashbuckle?

**UPDATE**

Here is my swagger config:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{        
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        config 
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {                        
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "ZipCodeWebApi.API");                        
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\App_Data\ZipCodeWebApi.API.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));                        
                    c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();                       
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {                        
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Until you make change in your webapi route it won't show in swagger, as this is not a valid route.

Answer (score 1):

As you are already saying [FromUri], your action method will show up in swagger only if you remove the Route attribute.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri]List<string> foo, string bar)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: No dice. Ill post my swagger config

Comment: Your api definition is wrong that is the reason why it is not showing. You should learn about route and how parameter routing works in WEB API.

Comment: No, the routing works. There is a route prefix on the controller and I can use this API method. It just doesnt show up in Swagger. See my update